# How to get the values of multiple input

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of products with different values.

```
const products = [{id: 2, value: 'A'}, {id:3, value: '3'}] // sample input

const RenderProduct = products.map((product) => {

   return(
     <div key={product.id}>
       <MinusIcon onClick={SHOULD_DEDUCT_THE_QUANTITY}/>
        <input type="text" value={SHOULD_DISPLAY_THE_QUANTITY_HERE} />
       <AddIcon onClick={SHOULD_ADD_THE_QUANTITY}/>
     </div>
   )
});

return <RenderProduct />
```

[image]

How can I retrieve the current quantity of each product and display it on inputbox?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a state using `useState` and based on the `operation` and `id` you can get the updated value

[`CODESANDBOX LINK`](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-dawn-frtu2l?file=/src/App.tsx)

```
function Button({ onClick, operation }: any) {
  return <button onClick={onClick}> {operation} </button>;
}

export default function App() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([
    { id: 2, value: 2 },
    { id: 3, value: 3 }
  ]);

  function handleChange(id: number, operation: "minus" | "add") {
    setProducts((p) => {
      return p.map((product) => {
        if (product.id !== id) return product;
        return {
          ...product,
          value: operation === "minus" ? product.value - 1 : product.value + 1
        };
      });
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      {products.map((product) => {
        return (
          <div key={product.id}>
            <Button
              operation="-"
              onClick={() => handleChange(product.id, "minus")}
            />
            <input type="text" value={product.value} />
            <Button
              operation="+"
              onClick={() => handleChange(product.id, "add")}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```